# How to send a reference of this?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I'm doing my first project with c++ following the MVC pattern. I have a controller class, Session, which has all functions to manage the class "ClientTsFrm", a view. What I want to do it's to communicate to the view class all events that happen. To do that, I'm using the observer pattern, in fact this implementation [1](https://github.com/juanchopanza/cppblog/blob/master/Patterns/Observer/)

Session.h Session is also a singleton.

```
#pragma once

#include "User.h"
#include "Config.h"

#include "../data/message.h"

#include <list>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include "../lib/eventtype.h"
#include "../lib/Subject.h"

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>
#else
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#endif
#include <wx/richtext/richtextctrl.h>
#include <wx/grid.h>


typedef std::list<UserPTR> UserList;
typedef std::shared_ptr<UserList> UserListPTR;

/* 
 * Set and get functions
 */

class Session: public Subject<EventTS>{
public:
    static Session* Instance();
    private:
    Session();  // Private so that it can  not be called
    Session(Session const&){};             // copy constructor is private
    Session& operator=(Session const&){};  // assignment operator is private
    static Session* m_pInstance;
public:
private:
    Session* m_instance;
    ConfigPTR m_config;
    UserListPTR m_luser;
    char* m_translationEngine;
    MessageQueuePTR m_pending;
    MessageQueuePTR m_queue;
};
```

Subject.h

```
//
// Copyright (c) 2013 Juan Palacios juan.palacios.puyana@gmail.com
// Subject to the BSD 2-Clause License
// - see < http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause>
//
#ifndef SUBJECT_H_
#define SUBJECT_H_
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility> // for std::forward
template <typename Event>
class Subject
{
public:
Subject()=default;
template <typename Observer>
void registerObserver(const Event& event, Observer&& observer)
{
observers_[event].push_back(std::forward<Observer>(observer));
}
template <typename Observer>
void registerObserver(Event&& event, Observer&& observer)
{
observers_[std::move(event)].push_back(std::forward<Observer>(observer));
}
void notify(const Event& event) const
{
for (const auto& obs : observers_.at(event)) obs();
}
// disallow copying and assigning
Subject(const Subject&)=delete;
Subject& operator=(const Subject&)=delete;
private:
std::map<Event, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> observers_;
};
#endif // SUBJECT_H_
```

ClientTsFrm.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __BORLANDC__
#pragma hdrstop
#endif

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>
#else
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#endif

#include "../Data/config.h"
#include "../lib/ClientTS.h"
#include "../data/Session.h"
#include "../data/Message.h"  

#include "FrmMailSending.h"
#include "FrmSettingMail.h"
#include "AudioWizard.h"
#include "NationList.h"
#include "LoginWarnings.h" 
#include "../ArchiveLog.h"

#include "FrmSaveChat.h"

#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/timer.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/richtext/richtextctrl.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
#include <wx/button.h>
#include <wx/grid.h>

#include "../GlobalVariables.h"
#include "../translateController/translateController.h"
#include "../translateController/translateVariable.h"

#include <list>
//#include "../lib/Observer.h"

#define MENU_ESCI 1800
#define MENU_OPZIONI 1801
#define MENU_SPEECH 1802



class ClientTsFrm : public wxFrame
{

    ClientTsFrm(LoginWarnings *warn, wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id = 1, const wxString &title = wxT("TeamTranslate"),
        const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
        long style = wxCAPTION | wxSYSTEM_MENU | wxCLOSE_BOX | wxRESIZE_BORDER);

    virtual ~ClientTsFrm(){};
    ClientTsFrm(const  ClientTsFrm& tg) {
        std::cout << "\tSimpleCat(SimpleCat&) called\n";
    }

    void updatePanelMsg();
private:
    unsigned int curRow;            //Initialize Row index
    unsigned int curCol;            //Initialize Column index
    Session* session;
    ConfigPTR config;
    NationList *nations;
    int REFRESHTIMER = 0;
    uint64 _sclogID;
    wxTimer *WxTimer2;
    wxTimer *WxTimer1;
    wxButton *btnspeech;
    wxRichTextCtrl *txtclient;
    wxTextCtrl *txtlingua;
    wxStaticText *lbllingua;
    wxStaticText *lblnick;
    wxTextCtrl *txtnick;
    wxRichTextCtrl *txtchat;
    wxButton *btnsend;
    wxTextCtrl *txtmsg;
    wxGrid *gridchat;
    wxGrid *gridclient;
    wxBoxSizer *sizer;
    wxGridSizer *gridsizer;
    wxMenuBar *WxMenuBar1;
    wxMenu *ID_MNU_FILE_1001_Mnu_Obj;
    wxMenu *ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj;
    wxBitmapButton *WxBitmapButton1;
    ClientTS clientts;
};
```

ClientTS.cpp. This is how I register the object

```
...
session->registerObserver(EventTS::MSG_RCV, std::bind(notifyMSG, *this));
...


 void notifyMSG(ClientTsFrm *fn)

{

    fn->updatePanelMsg();
}
```

Basically, I'm registering ClientTSFrm object. It's stored in session class and when an event happens, session calls the "notify" function from the subject class. This function calls the function of ClientTSFrm (the observer) which is send also the object. At the end, this function calls a function of ClientTSFrm  class in order to update the content.

If I compile, it shows this error:

> Error 28  error C2664: 'void (ClientTsFrm *)' : cannot convert argument
>   1 from 'ClientTsFrm' to 'ClientTsFrm *'   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional  1149    1

https://github.com/juanchopanza/cppblog/blob/master/Patterns/Observer/

Comment: Try `std::bind(notifyMSG, this)`. Far too much code to offer any more help.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, it works, but is it not just a copy of "this"?? I wonder this, because using an attribute of my class (the grid variable), the program crashes.

Comment: Remember the KISS principle.

Comment: @Daniel976034: `this` is a pointer, so copying it gives another pointer to the same object, which sounds like what you want. Binding `*this`, as you tried to do, would copy the object, which is probably not what you want; especially if the function expects a pointer, not an object or reference. The crash implies either the object has been destroyed, or something has corrupted memory. You'll need your debugger to investigate that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Please, any advice?

MikeSeymour and what function can i use instead of bind?

Comment: @Daniel976034: Just use pointers. This experimentation with rvalue references and stuff is leading you astray. Btw. I've only tried out WxWidgets (if that's what it is) in a card game program and I remember thinking there must be some better way. Not sure what I'd recommend though.